# Navigation in Jetpack Compose keeps crashing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to use Navigation to access a single function with a parameter, from two different functions. When I try it in the emulator, the app crashes. The app builds normally.

I'm using compose 1.0.1 and navigation 2.5.0

This is the Navigation function:

```
@Composable
fun Nav() {

    val navController = rememberNavController()

    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "Main") {
        composable("Main") { Main() }
        composable("Detail/{name}") { backStackEntry ->
            Detail(backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("name").toString())
        }
        composable("Info") { Info(navController) }
        composable("Table") { Table(navController) }
    }
}
```

This is the Main function, here I use TabRow to navigate between screens:

```
@Composable
fun Main() {
    val tabs = listOf(TabItem.Table, TabItem.Info)
    val tabNum = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    
    Scaffold(bottomBar = {
        TabRow(modifier = Modifier.backgroudn(Color.Gray), selectedTabIndex = tabNum.value) {
            tabs.forEachIndexed { index, tab ->
                Tab(text = { Text(tab.title) }, selected = tabNum.value == index, onClick = { tabNum.value = index })
            }
        }
    }) {
        Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()) {
            tabs[tabNum.value].screen()
        }
    }
}
```

This is the TabItem sealed class, used for the navigation:

```
typealias ComposableFun = @Composable () -> Unit

sealed class TabItem(var title: String, var screen: ComposableFun) {
    object Table : TabItem("Table", { Table(rememberNavController()) })
    object Info : TabItem("Info", { Info(rememberNavController()) })
}
```

This is a shorter version of the Table function:

```
@Composable
fun Table(navController: NavController) {
    val elements1: List<String> = listOf("H", "Li", "Na", "K", "Rb", "Cs", "Fr")

    Column {
        elements1.forEach { i ->
            Box(modifier = Modifier.size(75.dp).padding(1.dp).clickable(onClick = {
                navController.navigate("Detail/$i")
            })) {
                Canvas(modifier = Modifier.size(75.dp), onDraw = {
                    drawRect(color = Color.Red)
                })
                Text(text = i, fontSize = 30.sp)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Info function:

```
@Composable
fun Info(navController: NavController) {

    val elements: List<String> = listOf("H", "He", "Li", "Be", "B", "C", "N", "O", "F", "Ne", "Na")

    Column {
        elements.forEach { i ->
            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .size(width = 1000.dp, height = 50.dp)
                .padding(5.dp)
                .background(Color.Red)
                .clickable(onClick = {
                    navController.navigate("Detail/$i")
                })) {
                Text(text = text i, fontSize = 30.sp)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a shorter version of the Detail function:

```
@Composable
fun Detail(name: String) {
    
    Column {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.size(75.dp).padding(1.dp)) {
            Canvas(modifier = Modifier.size(75.dp), onDraw = {
                drawRect(color = Color.Red)
            })
            Text(text = name, fontSize = 30.sp)
        }
    }
}
```

This is the crash log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.tavolaperiodica, PID: 8360
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1652)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1984)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate$default(NavController.kt:1979)
        at com.example.tavolaperiodica.TableKt$Table$1$1$1$1$1$1.invoke(Table.kt:50)
        at com.example.tavolaperiodica.TableKt$Table$1$1$1$1$1$1.invoke(Table.kt:49)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.ClickableKt$clickable$4$gesture$1$2.invoke-k-4lQ0M(Clickable.kt:137)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.ClickableKt$clickable$4$gesture$1$2.invoke(Clickable.kt:137)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.TapGestureDetectorKt$detectTapAndPress$2$1$1.invokeSuspend(TapGestureDetector.kt:378)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.resume(DispatchedTask.kt:178)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.dispatch(DispatchedTask.kt:166)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.dispatchResume(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:397)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:431)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl$default(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:420)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeWith(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:328)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.SuspendingPointerInputFilter$PointerEventHandlerCoroutine.offerPointerEvent(SuspendingPointerInputFilter.kt:432)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.SuspendingPointerInputFilter.dispatchPointerEvent(SuspendingPointerInputFilter.kt:330)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.SuspendingPointerInputFilter.onPointerEvent-H0pRuoY(SuspendingPointerInputFilter.kt:343)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.Node.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:287)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.Node.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:275)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.Node.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:275)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.NodeParent.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:151)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.HitPathTracker.dispatchChanges(HitPathTracker.kt:90)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.PointerInputEventProcessor.process-gBdvCQM(PointerInputEventProcessor.kt:77)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.dispatchTouchEvent(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:860)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:440)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1830)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3400)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:398)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12752)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5106)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4909)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4585)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7092)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7061)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7022)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7195)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:186)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
        Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [androidx.compose.runtime.BroadcastFrameClock@3ef7ee, StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@a6e448f, AndroidUiDispatcher@f70f31c]
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8360 SIG: 9
```

Comment: what is crash log error

Answer (score 2):

The issue is your `TabItem` sealed class. When the `Table` object and the `Info` object are created they called `rememberNavController()` and that cause to create a new `NavController` instance for your activity. It's mean that you are overriding the `NavController` that you create in the Nav composable function.

You should follow the principle mention in the documentation:

> You should create the NavController in the place in your composable hierarchy where all composables that need to reference it have access to it. This follows the principles of state hoisting and allows you to use the NavController and the state it provides via currentBackStackEntryAsState() to be used as the source of truth for updating composables outside of your screens. See Integration with the bottom navbar for an example of this functionality.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#getting-started